# does anyone know how I can fix this?

Tags: python, materials

[image]does anyone know how I can fix this ? I'm using blender 2.8 and every time I put it in material mode, the texture is visible and transparent at the same time this model is ported from blender 2.79 i reused its materials maybe this is the problem i would have to make new materials from scratch this happens when i export to some format for example fbx and import the same in the program

maybe some problem with python?

Comment: Hello, it may be a combination of inverted normals, default metallic material not initialized properly, or custom split normals

Comment: I already tried to recalculate the normals and it continues the same thing this bug only happens when I put it in material mode and when rendering in solid it is normal

Comment: The fact that it's happening in material mode makes me think that it's the eevee engine having difficulty displaying your 2.79 materials - particularly with regards to transparency. Go down the list material properties, and near where it says "Blend Mode" there should be a checkbox for "Backface Culling". Try toggling it on and off and see if it makes a difference. If it doesn't, try changing the blend mode to "alpha blend" which will enable another checkbox labelled "Show Backface". Try toggling that on or off as well.

Comment: man the problem itself is not and set this when it is in the blender when I disable Backface Culling and export when imporot the format I exported into the blender this option activates alone